# CI redirecting to live server as well, but it can't redirect to localhost when I want to edit some code in my localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I want to edit some code in my company website using my localhost. But when I type `localhost/mysite` it always redirecting to live server (this web is already released on live server).

I've change some code in config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';
```

database.php :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

routes.php :

```
$route['default_controller']    = 'frontend';
$route['404_override']          = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']  = FALSE;
```

and etc just to make it redirecting to my localhost but nothing change. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Just check if .htaccess file is effecting it ?

Comment: I've already edit the .htaccess file to default but nothing change